# any way to detect volume key presses or volume changes with android service?

Tags: android, service, volume, detect

Some Android apps generate a notification when the device's volume changes and some lock the volume.  For the life of me, I cannot find out how that's done.  Please, can someone help me by providing an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Broadcast Action to detect volume changes, but you could maybe every second or two check what the volume is with `getStreamVolume` and if you need to lock it at a specific volume, every second or two use: `setStreamVolume`

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.htm for more info.

You could use the AlarmManager class or a handler to check the volume every second or so.

If it's an activity, you can override `onKeyDown` to detect key presses. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is one way you can do in service by using Content Observer. It works like a broadcast receiver, listen to the event of changing content such as volume, contacts, call log...

Using the following code in your service

```
public class VolumeService extends Service{ 
AudioManager mAudioManager;
Handler mHandler;

private ContentObserver mVolumeObserver = new ContentObserver(mHandler) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        if (mAudioManager != null) {

            final int volume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            System.out.println("Volume thay đổi: " +volume);

            Intent photoIntent = new Intent(VolumeService.this,TakePhotoActivity.class);
            photoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(photoIntent);
        }
    }
};





@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    System.out.println("Volume Service started");

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    Uri uri = Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS[AudioManager.STREAM_RING]);
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, mVolumeObserver);

    System.out.println("Đã đăng ký Volume listener");
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();      
    System.out.println("Volume service destroied");

    getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mVolumeObserver);
}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

}
```

Don't forget to declare it in the Android Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".service.VolumeService" >
```

Comment: ya its work when phone in not locked but not when phone is locked!!??

Comment: Hello dear,
is there option to get Key detection while phone is locked?

Comment: `Settings.System.VOLUME_SETTINGS` is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it, you could just fix to a set volume instead of changing. My goal was to adjust system volume Service.

Also, avoid doing this only when needed.

```
public class VolumeKeyController {

    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession;
    private final Context mContext;

    public VolumeKeyController(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private void createMediaSession() {
        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(mContext, KeyUtil.log);

        mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(new Builder()
                .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 0)
                .build());
        mMediaSession.setPlaybackToRemote(getVolumeProvider());
        mMediaSession.setActive(true);
    }

    private VolumeProviderCompat getVolumeProvider() {
        final AudioManager audio = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int STREAM_TYPE = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
        int currentVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE);
        int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(STREAM_TYPE);
        final int VOLUME_UP = 1;
        final int VOLUME_DOWN = -1;

        return new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_RELATIVE, maxVolume, currentVolume) {
            @Override
            public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
                // Up = 1, Down = -1, Release = 0
                // Replace with your action, if you don't want to adjust system volume
                if (direction == VOLUME_UP) {
                    audio.adjustStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE,
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                }
                else if (direction == VOLUME_DOWN) {
                    audio.adjustStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE,
                            AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                }
                setCurrentVolume(audio.getStreamVolume(STREAM_TYPE));
            }
        };
    }

    // Call when control needed, add a call to constructor if needed immediately
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        if (mMediaSession != null) {
            mMediaSession.setActive(active);
            return;
        }
        createMediaSession();
    }

    // Call from Service's onDestroy method
    public void destroy() {
        if (mMediaSession != null) {
            mMediaSession.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture volume/hardware key events by using accessibility service.

[How to capture key events inside a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229929/how-to-capture-key-events-inside-a-service/59064820#59064820)