# Observing volume changes made by apps

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a ContentObserver registered to android.provider.Settings.System that should observe changes of any audio volume. It is notified as expected when clicking the hardware volume buttons but is not notified when I change the audio volume via AudioManager.setStreamVolume or AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume.

Here's how my ContentObserver looks like:

```java
// this is a Service
this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
  android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, 
  true, new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
      Log.d("ContentObserver", "got notified");
    }
});
```

And here my call to AudioManager.adjustStreamVolume:

```java
// this.context is the activities context
this.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE).adjustStreamVolume(
  AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
  AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7297242/1168892) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6896746/1168892) post and the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) and [Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) documentation and can not find a reason why the Observer is notified when changing the volume with the volume buttons but not when changing it with the AudioManager.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AudioManager does broadcast an intent

> android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION`

But this is not part of the official documentation. So this might change in future releases. But you could use this atleast for gingerbread devices.

you can find more about the extras in the intent from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/media/AudioService.java#AudioService.sendVolumeUpdate%28int%29)

Comment: I still don't really know why the Service is not notified when adjustStreamVolume is called, but this answer solves my problem that it *should be notified*. I've found out that the volume buttons don't call set/adjustStreamVolume but shouldn't everything result in a change of Settings.System?

Comment: Looking at the link that points to the extras in the intent, this event is broadcast only when the SCO volume changes ...

Comment: What do we import for content observer? Thanks!