(Android Kotlin) Is there an equivalent of "onKeyDown" for foreground services?
I'd like to be able to detect when the volume buttons are being pressed in a foreground service. When the activity is still active, I just override the onKeyDown method in said activity and check for the appropriate keycodes.
I tried to look for an equivalent method for detecting this from a foreground service, to no avail. I'm not sure if there's a way to do this during a foreground service (maybe there's a technique using a broadcast receiver?).

possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297242/any-way-to-detect-volume-key-presses-or-volume-changes-with-android-service

Thank you very much dev.tejasb! Before I asked the question yesterday, I did a search ahead of time but didn't find anything, but it looks like you found the query that might just put me on the right track. Peace and God bless! Appreciate the fast response!
