# Handling headset buttons before Voice Search on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Android Jelly Bean introduced a voice search which activates with a long-press on the play/pause button of a headset. As my app requires being able to utilise these long-presses, I was wondering if there is any way to either disable the voice search or make Android play fair with the button events.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it myself, but you may be able to get this to work using the AudioManager's [registerMediaButtonEventReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(android.content.ComponentName)) method, as the volume buttons are media buttons.

The AOSP music app has a [MediaButtonIntentReceiver](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java) that responds to volume button presses.

Credit for this solution belongs to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510564/1023092).

Comment: I'm afraid not. In Android 4.0+, all media button receivers have to use `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` to receive button clicks. This part still works, but sadly doesn't make Android give the intent to third party apps before handling Voice Search.

Comment: The Pressy app is able to hook a long press of the headset button (even on Lollipop). Pressy has a specific interface with a 'go' button which presumably fires some intent and forces the system to ask if you want to make Pressy or Google Search the default. I would love to know how it achieves it.