# How to listen volume key event in background of Android application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm making an application that run in background after install and do some task as volume down key is pressed at any point of time in Android. I have created a service of it but it doesn't listen to key event as application closes and run in background. Application is not for media player.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792606/android-listener-for-hard-keys-press-at-background)

Answer (score -1):

See the following:
[Volume change Listener: Is registerMediaButtonEventReceiver preferable to onKeyDown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234176/volume-change-listener-is-registermediabuttoneventreceiver-preferable-to-onkeyd)

You can register to this event from a service and that should do the work for you.