# guaranteed image visibility in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, user-interface

Is it possible to constantly display a picture at the "front layer" (e.g. a special canvas) of the Android GUI?
I want, that this picture is **always visible** - independent of the current android-status;

*I know that this could effect the functionallity of the system - but is it possible?*

- My specific goal: my appliaction should show an image (over the whole
  screen), whenever the volume- AND power-button are pressed at the
  same time. The image should be displayed for the duration of pressing
  the buttons.

Comment: You should get your hands dirty with a custom ROM in order to do that!

Comment: well, that's the answer I was afraid of:)  - I was hoping that there is a possibility for the visualization of the graphic without having to interfere into the system(or ROM).  Is there a way to accomplish the permanent visualisation by an app?  (the "button activity" is not relevant- relevant is the image)

Comment: Theoretically you could do that with a Launcher app but i am not fully aware by the possible permissions you might need and if Android provides them!

Comment: Allow me to ask a naive question: 

Could i invoke a kind of popup-window after a special event happened- and the window is showing the image? 
and  after a certain time the window is automatically closed? 

would that work?

Comment: If that special event is firing a Broadcast Intent that you can catch and then proceed with your actions, yes i guess that it will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do this. You'd have to have a service running in the background to detect the volume change and display a floating window:

Volume detection in background service:
[Listen to volume buttons in background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154118/listen-to-volume-buttons-in-background-service)

Floating windows (ala Facebook chatheads):
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Comment: thank you, this could be the solution! do you know if chatheads could be only drawn on top of any app or also to on top of the standard android interface (without a displayed App-GUI)? EDIT: just found the solution- it is possible to draw over the Android-UI!  I will try this approach and let you know if it succeeded!