# Receive sound button click when the phone is locked

Tags: android, wakelock, locked

I need to receive long sound button press event even if my phone is locked.

I tried using SettingsContentObserver and AudioManager but it only works when the music is playing. 
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292255/4757621

Currently I am creating wakelock in OnCreate method to keep CPU running when phone is locked but still, no success.

Any ideas?