# How to detect volume change in android?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

As many of you might know, Android has many volume streams such as:

```
STREAM_ALARM        The audio stream for alarms
STREAM_DTMF         The audio stream for DTMF Tones
STREAM_MUSIC        The audio stream for music playback
STREAM_NOTIFICATION The audio stream for notifications
STREAM_RING         The audio stream for the phone ring
STREAM_SYSTEM       The audio stream for system sounds
STREAM_VOICE_CALL   The audio stream for phone calls
```

I have been using content observer. I can detect change in one volume stream so far but I would like to know how to detect change in any of the aforementioned streams. I have followed the approach in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292255/2433261

Edit: Before you flag this question as duplicate, please notice that I want to detect change if any of the volume streams changes in amplitude.