# Cannot resolve symbol 'MediaSessionCompat'

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I cannot import `MediaSessionCompat`.
The import statement for importing the whole `android.support.v4.media` library does not show up in the Android Studio "IntelliSense" and it cannot resolve the symbol for anything inside it.

Do I have to make some kind of extra configuration to get this import, like in app `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add these to your dependencies and sync Gradle:

---

#### Pre-AndroidX

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

---

#### Post-AndroidX

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.6.0'
```

---

**Note** from official documentation:

> With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

Comment: The latest dependencies as at (September 30th, 2020) are: 

implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.1' and implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.2.0'

Answer (score 16):

The latest dependencies are:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'
```

Comment: The latest dependencies as at (September 30th, 2020) are: 

implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.1' and implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

```
 def core_version = "1.9.0"

// Java language implementation
implementation "androidx.core:core:$core_version"
// Kotlin
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_version"

implementation "androidx.media:media:1.6.0"
```