# How to catch up events from controls below steering wheel in my car

Tags: android, controls, media

Have a car with controls below steering wheel. Buttons are: next/previous track, volume up/down, ok, source. I want catch up Next/Previous track button.

I've tried `onKeyDown` in my activity with no luck. Also i've tried `BroadcastReceiver` and `MediaButtonReceiver` with no effect. Seems that application didn't see any events. Debug possibilities on device is very small, they are absent in fact.

1. Is there way to catch such event?
2. How in android find some hardware connected to phone. May be some enumerator class for every connected device?

Update 1:

I'd tried:

1.

```
<receiver
   android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
     <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
  android:name=".OrionPlaybackService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true"
  tools:ignore="ExportedService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>

public class OrionPlaybackService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
  private MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat;
  ...
  private final MediaSessionCompat.Callback callback = new 
    MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onMediaButtonEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent");
      static_functions.addLocalLogRecord(getApplicationContext(), "onMediaButtonEvent");
      return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
      }
    ...
}
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "Service created");
    static_functions.addLocalLogRecord(getApplicationContext(), "Service created");
    if (mediaSessionCompat==null) {
      mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "OrionPlaybackService");
 mediaSessionCompat.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
 mediaSessionCompat.setCallback(callback);
 mediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);
  }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Command received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "Command received");
    static_functions.addLocalLogRecord(getApplicationContext(), "Command received");
    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSessionCompat, intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }
}
```

2. Create Receiver programatically, using

   ```
   createReceiver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
     //intentFilter.setPriority(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
     intentFilter.setPriority(999);
     context.registerReceiver(new SteeringWheelReceiver(), intentFilter);
     }
   });
   ```

with two priorities 999 and 7FFF FFFF.

3. Create receiver with

   ```
   createReceiver2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           ComponentName mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(context, SteeringWheelReceiver.class);
           audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
           Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver 2 registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
   ```
4. Create receiver with

   ```
   createReceiver3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           ComponentName mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(context, OrionPlaybackService.class);
           audioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
           Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver 3 registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
   ```

My class SteeringWheel were

```
public class SteeringWheelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "onMediaButtonEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(static_variables.TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent");
    static_functions.addLocalLogRecord(context, "onMediaButtonEvent");
  }
}
```

6. Test buttons Were

   ```
   sendBroadcast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
           context.sendBroadcast(intent);
       }
   });

   emulateMedia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
           KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY);
           audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(keyEvent);
           keyEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY);
           audioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(keyEvent);
       }
   });
   ```
7. So when I do nothing, or create receiver with one of variants(no matter) when I click any of `Test buttons` i see toast, log message and other. When I try press `Next track` on steering wheel I have no message. Like nothing happens and.
8. It's not Media buttons? But what? USB numerator shows me two devices 1. Modem 2. Flash card. Input devices show me 3 devices, touch screen, something else? no matter, and `rk29-keypad` - i suppose that's my device.
9. VLC player working with media buttons with no problems. VLC have an open source. But copy/paste(see methods above) gives me nothing.

I'm starting believe in miracles...

Comment: In what way android device is connected your steering wheel buttons?

Comment: Actually I don't know. That's one more problem. I can't disassembly my car ) I think it's an USB.

Comment: As I understood you already tried this one https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#mediabuttons-and-active-mediasessions

Comment: Yes. Exactly this one article. Both ways. My Android is 4.4.2

Comment: If it is USB you can try to list connected devices https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host#enumerate-devices you can try to connect to it, and in experimental way found command for your buttons

Comment: If there is an opportunity to read logs, maybe some are wrote in logcat, when button is pressed. You need something to start with)

Comment: I'll try to enumerate USB devices for now. There is no logcat, only toast, but this bad idea ) Device even didn't show error if there is exception in application, it's just close it. Very small debug possibilities. And more, my car in other part of city, because of that only one test by day )

Comment: Dis it work? Is it USB?

Comment: Checked it only yesterday ) No, it didn't ( Enumeration gives me two devices. First is my USB modem, second is USB flash. Have no idea what connection can it be... if it's CAN or something like this, than it should act as keyboard and `onKeyDown` must work. I pretty new in android(less than 2 years), and may be you know any other connection possibilities?

Comment: You can check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510564/3858030

Comment: This is variant of article from above. A little different registration process, but same input. Through `broadcastreceiver` which didn't work. I will try tonight, but I think I know result )

Comment: Didn't work. I'd disassembly one application which works on device with no problem. In manifest i saw only standard receiver `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>` and... that's all, my knowledge of smali not so good ) Will try tomorrow check all again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Vital were three things(though don't know why first are)

1. All registeration of receivers should be done in Service. Not using button in activity. All in service. Also 2 and 3.
2. I forgot about

`mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);`

And other apps(built-in) takes focus.

3. Android 4.4.2 have `RemoteControlClient` instead of `MediaSessionCompat`. Possibly depends on current testing device(Non standard).