# Implementing hot key to launch specific Activity

Tags: android, shell

I want to launch an activity when a user press home key for the specific number of times. For example if the user press 3 times home key than he can see the specific activity running on android.

Is it possible?

Comment: Some discussion about capturing key events while in the background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229929/how-to-capture-key-events-inside-a-service

Comment: simple app can not capture `Home Key` event!